# How do I get my remote branch URL from the GitHub "Create pull request" page?

Tags: github

I went to a GitHub repository I'm not a member of, edited a file, and committed my changes. Now I'm at this "Comparing changes" screen:

[image]

I don't want to create a pull request *yet* because I want to add additional changes, and I want to do it locally (as opposed to on the GitHub website). To do that, I need the URL of my fork and/or my branch. **Is there a way to visit that URL by performing an action on this page?**

I've been unable to find a way of getting that red or (preferably) orange URL from this page. Is there a way to get it here? My solution is to open a new tab, find my fork, and click on the green "Code <>" button (screenshot below).

Since I often want this URL on the "Comparing changes" page, I expected to find a link on this page that takes me to my fork (i.e., `https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jquery`), or better yet, directly to my new branch (i.e., `https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jquery/tree/patch-1`).

---

The following information is to clarify the above. If you already understood what I was asking, you can ignore it.

To put it another way, I'm looking for the red line in this picture:

[image]

Or better yet, the URL of the `patch-1` branch which... doesn't seem to exist in this dropdown for some reason? See the purple line in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If it helps at all, `git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git` is the SSH format. You can see both of these information on the page, but yes, it sucks to have to type it manually.

Comment: @EagertoLearn 100%. To your knowledge, is this the best solution out there?

Comment: I'm just a novice at this. But i did spend a bit playing with the GitHub interface to see if i could dig something up while minimizing clicks - I didn't. It might just be the most robust solution for now, until GitHub adds the feature. I even tried hitting the `.` key to see if it would launch into the web editor, but it doesn't do that on the PR page.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create a [Tampermonkey userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to solve the problem.

[image]

Here's the code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Add repo/branch links to GitHub's "Comparing Changes" page
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.7
// @description  This adds a link to the fork's branch on the GitHub "Comparing changes" page (AKA the "Create a Pull Request" page). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77623282/how-do-i-get-my-remote-branch-url-from-the-github-create-pull-request-page for more details.
// @author       DanKaplanSES
// @match        https://github.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=github.com
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js
// @grant        none
// @license MIT
// ==/UserScript==

const browseRepoHtml = `<div class="browse-repo"><a href="#" target="_blank">Browse Repo</a></div>`;
const browseBranchHtml = `<div class="browse-branch"><a href="#" target="_blank">Browse Branch</a></div>`;

jQuery.noConflict(true)(function ($) {
  function modifyPage() {
    if (location.pathname.indexOf(`/compare/`) === -1) {
      return;
    }
    const isPageAlreadyModified = $(`#browse-link-0`).length > 0;
    if (isPageAlreadyModified) {
      return;
    }

    $(`.range-cross-repo-pair details`).wrap(
      `<div class="details-container"></div>`
    );

    $(`.details-container`).each(function (index) {
      const containerType =
        $(this).find(`summary.branch`).length > 0 ? `branch` : `repo`;
      const html = containerType === `repo` ? browseRepoHtml : browseBranchHtml;
      const href = hrefString(containerType, index);
      const containerContentsHidden = $(this).find(`details`).is(`:hidden`);
      $(this)
        .css({ 'display': containerContentsHidden ? `none` : `inline-block` })
        .append(html)
        .css({ 'text-align': `center` })
        .find(`a`)
        .attr({ id: `browse-link-${index}`, href });
    });

    $(`.range-editor .pre-mergability, .range-editor .d-inline-block`).css({
      'vertical-align': `top`,
    });
  }

  function hrefString(containerType, index) {
    switch (containerType) {
      case 'repo':
        return `/` + $(`.css-truncate-target`)[index].textContent;
      case 'branch':
        return (
          `/` +
          $(`.css-truncate-target`)[index - 1].textContent +
          `/tree/` +
          $(`.css-truncate-target`)[index].textContent
        );
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unexpected hrefType: ${hrefType}`);
    }
  }

  const pageReadyForModification =
    $(`.range-cross-repo-pair details`).length > 0;
  if (pageReadyForModification) {
    modifyPage();
  }

  setInterval(modifyPage, 1500);
});
```

Here's [a link to the script on Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/481652-add-repo-branch-links-to-github-s-comparing-changes-page).